# jsPDF addImage outputs grey square

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, drawimage

I'm trying to generate a pdf using jsPDF 2.4.0 in a react. It all goes without any error but for output I only get a grey square with some random pixels

```js
import React from 'react';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

import testImage from './testImage.png';

const loadImage: (url: string) => Promise<string> = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const c = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    const i = new Image();
    i.onload = () => {
      c.width = i.width;
      c.height = i.height;

      if (ctx) {
        ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
      }

      resolve(c.toDataURL('image/png'));
    };

    i.src = url;
  });
};

function PdfExport() {
    const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = React.useState<string | undefined>();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'portrait',
            format: [8.3, 11.7],
            unit: 'in',
        });

        loadImage(testImage).then((img) => {
            pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 1, 1, 1, 1);
            var blobPDF = new Blob([pdf.output()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            setPdfUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF));
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <iframe src={pdfUrl} />
    );
}

export default PdfExport;
```

And when mounted the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwTkr.png).

Am I missing something here? Everything else works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

`//React code here

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', false);

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 600, 0, undefined, false);

pdf.save("download.pdf");`
```